# given string of braces both open and closed tell if it's a valid string

Tags: algorithm

This is the very simple in O(n) but I was asked to do it in less than O(n) time complexity.

e.g.

```
{({})} is a valid string because each type of opening brace has a matching closing brace. 
while for {{{{)))} this is not as braces doesn't match
```

Comment: I assume the nesting is relevant too? ie `({)}` is not valid? Also I can't think of how this could be done in less than O(n) since that is the minimum you need to look at every character and I can't conceive of a way you could do this without looking at every character...

Comment: You have to potentially read each character in the string which is itself O(n).

Comment: if `n` is the length of the string, I find it hard to believe that sub-`O(n)` is possible - in general, you *have* to examine every character...

Comment: Maybe checking that the string is not valid can be done in less than O(n).

Comment: Are you sure that the question is correct? If it is correct, maybe it's captious.

Comment: @Chris right that will be invalid

Answer (score 2):

If n is the length of the string, the algorithm complexity can't be less than O(n), because if there is any character the algorithm didn't check, it can't be sure of whether the character is a brace or not. So, it can't be less than O(n).

Comment: I might be O(n) of memory usage.

Comment: @AntonSizikov It does say "O(n) **time** complexity". In terms of space, I think it should be doable in O(1) space.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to do that in O(1) of memory.

Comment: You can't do that in O(1) memory because constant memory computation class is equal to the class of regular languages and the language of balanced parentheses is not a regular language.

Comment: @pkacprzak I'm not really following your comment, but I believe you can do it in O(1) memory using counters (I'm pretty sure I have managed to at some point a while back).

Comment: @Dukeling counters are not constant memory

Comment: @Dukeling pkacprzak is correct here. It is grammatically impossible unless you introduce some extra fundamental constraint.

Comment: @pkacprzak Yes, I suppose you're right. But given that the string has to be longer than 18446744073709551615 characters (or 2x that with an optimization) for a counter to not fit into a 64-bit integer any more, I just considered that constant memory.

Comment: @Dukeling following your arguments any algorithm has O(1) time complexity, because we always have limited data size

Comment: @pkacprzak I did say "I suppose you're right". But just to defend my case - I don't know about you, but I haven't seen a string longer than 18446744073709551615 characters (i.e. 16777216 TB) recently (and below this would take 8 bytes).

Comment: @Dukeling I suppose no one sees longer containing only brackets :)

Comment: @everybody is right and i was too (in answering him), this was asked from someone in interview. And he was told that it can be done in less than O(n) which puzzled me.

Answer (score 0):

You could of precalculate all the good strings for some reasonable length, put them in a huge hash table (not that huge actually, for instance all the good combinations for up to 12-character string would take only 10066 cells) and then do every check simply by looking into that table.

This could work for small strings and would of been very effective in general case, but... in the worse case it is still O(n).

Comment: this would be nice approach if braces are of single type we can store possible good combination.